# How to store OLS Regression Results F-statsistic and R-squared to a list

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, regression, statsmodels

How can I assign the OLS Regression Results F-statsistic and R-squared in a list? For example:

```
ols('x ~ a + b + c', data).fit()
ols_model.summary()

OLS Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  x         R-squared:    0.901
Model:  OLS               Adj. R-squared:   0.799
Method: Least Squares     F-statistic:  598.1
Date:   Thu, 08 jan 2013  Prob (F-statistic):   0.01
Time:   09:07:22          Log-Likelihood:   280.00
No. Observations:   110   AIC:  -910.0
Df Residuals:       250   BIC:  -910.1
Df Model:           3       
Covariance Type:    robust
```

I can store the output in a variable like this

```
x = model.rsquared

x

0,901
```

But then the following code leads to nothing:

```
df['x'] = x
```

`type(x)` gives `numpy.float64` btw.

Hope somebody can help! Thanks.

Comment: Like R, SAS, Stata, usually you wouldn't store model results in a dataset/dataframe but its predicted values across observations. And other packages usually maintain a matrix of coefficients/t-stats. Model results would usually go into reports.

Comment: Is there really no option? If I ask for type(x) ik get the message that its a numpy.float64 When trying to convert this to int() the output becomes 0 instead of 0,901.